# setlocale no codeblock windows sem funcionar direito

Tags: c, codificação-de-caracteres, locale

Tenho um projeto de programação que era pra desenvolver uma réplica d jogo de batalha naval. porem fiz todo o programa no Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) contudo meu professor utiliza windows(usando o codeblocks) e para garantir fui testar o mesmo no windows já havia adiciona a `locale.h` e o `setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese")` e a princípio o caractere `ç` apareceu normal, porém as letras `a`, `i`... acentuadas seja elas maiúsculas ou não ficam todas doidas. o Programa é dividido em vários arquivos e algum `printf` estão em outros arquivos. o `setlocale` está apenas no inicio do `main()`.

Comment: Confirme que o Codeblocks está com o `encoding` correto em `Settings -> Editor -> General settings -> Encoding Settings`